# Is conversion from existential quantifier to universal quantifier like this always possible?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am reading/testing a proof in Coq

```
Theorem ceval_step__ceval: forall c st st',
      (exists i, ceval_step st c i = Some st') -> c / st || st'.
```

The specific functions/definitions don't matter as they are not used. After a few steps, the theorem is transformed to a form where the inner existential quantifier is changed to a universal:

```
1 subgoals
______________________________________(1/1)
forall (c : com) (st st' : state) (i : nat),
ceval_step st c i = Some st' -> c / st || st'
```

This is basically,

```
Theorem ceval_step__ceval'': forall c st st', forall i
      ceval_step st c i = Some st' -> c / st || st'.
```

Although this is not exactly replacing `exists i` with `forall i` verbatim, I am kind of surprised. I was wondering if this kind of replacing existential quantifier with universals always possible, or when is this possible? What's the general rule/technique for this conversion?

(I vaguely remember something called skolemization but didn't quite understand it when learning it.)

The steps in Coq (8.4) to transform the theorem are:

```
Proof.
  intros c st st' H.
  inversion H as [i E].
  clear H.
  generalize dependent i.
  generalize dependent st'.
  generalize dependent st.
  generalize dependent c.
```

Comment: It's much easier to help if you post working code with all imports etc, and you simplify the problem as much as possible.

Comment: @KonstantinWeitz, thanks for your answer. I wanted to keep it short, and didn't want to simplify away the interesting part as I don't which part is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is always possible! You have stumbled upon [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) of dependent pairs. Using the [Curry-Howard Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), you can think of `exists a:A, P a` as a dependent pair consisting of a value `a` of type `A` and a proof of proposition `P` that depends on `a`. Following is the definition of a dependent curry/uncurry for `exists` products.

```
Variable A : Type.
Variable P : A -> Prop.
Variable Q : Prop.

Definition dependentCurryProp (h : (exists a:A, P a) -> Q) : forall a:A, P a -> Q :=
  fun a p => h (ex_intro _ a p).

Definition dependentUncurryProp (h : forall a:A, P a -> Q) : (exists a:A, P a) -> Q := 
  fun e => match e with ex_intro _ a p => h a p end.
```

You can write the same functions using the tactic language.

```
Lemma dependentCurryProd (h : (exists a:A, P a) -> Q) : forall a:A, P a -> Q.
  intros a p.
  apply h.
  exists a.
  apply p.
Qed.

Lemma dependentUncurryProd (h : forall a:A, P a -> Q) : (exists a:A, P a) -> Q.
  intros e.
  destruct e as [a p].
  eapply h.
  apply p.
Qed.
```

The same trick works for dependent products where the first value `a` is of type `A` and the second value `b` is of type `B a` (instead of a proof of a proposition). Such a product is called a sigma type `sigT A B` or `{a:A & B a}`.

```
Variable C : Type.
Variable B : A -> Type.

Definition dependentCurry (f : {a:A & B a} -> C) : forall a:A, B a -> C := 
  fun a b => f (existT _ a b).

Definition dependentUncurry (f : forall a:A, B a -> C) : {a:A & B a} -> C := 
  fun p => match p with existT _ a b => f a b end.
```

I don't think this has anything to do with skolemization.